# Mimicking a const reference with a wrapper class?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to hold a temporary in a wrapper class but can't figure it out.

I can hold a temporary in a const reference:

```
  const string& a = string("abc");
```

but fail to mimick this using a wrapper class, like:

```
  reference_wrapper<const string> b = cref( string("abc") );
```

> error: use of deleted function ‘void std::cref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp
> = __cxx11::basic_string]’   102 |   reference_wrapper b = cref( string("abc") );

I'm trying to avoid the destruction of the temporary like in the first code line. Is it possible to write a wrapper class that can hold constant references?

Comment: The error is telling you that `cref()` can't be called with a temporary/rvalue as its input, as it has explicitly `delete`'d that overload to forbid you from making that kind of call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The lifetime extension of temporaries when bound to references only applies to real reference variables directly used as local variables. Wrapper classes remove the special handling and will either not compile or lead to dangling references.